# Docker cli: docker run command with quoted arguments

Tags: docker, jestjs

I'm trying to run execute `jest -t` variant with the following Docker cli command:

```
docker run -it node-jest npx jest -t "This string matches exactly one test"
```

Which does not do the same thing if I were to run `npx jest -t "This string matches exactly one test"` locally.

It appears that double quotes are being stripped/ignored and only `This` is getting passed to `jest -t`. It appears that `This string matches exactly one test` is getting split up on spaces and treated as individual arguments. Can someone explain why that is happening, and how to get `"This string matches exactly one test"` passed in to `docker run` correctly (hopefully in a readable/sane way)?

Comment: try with /bin/bash -c 'npx jest -t "This string matches exactly one test"'

Comment: @LinPy That behaves as if only `npx` is executed by `docker run`.

Comment: I do not get you , what I mean trying this: `docker run -it node-jest  /bin/bash -c 'npx jest -t "This string matches exactly one test"' `

Comment: @LinPy Yes, that is what I ran. It only executes `npx` inside of the container, causing the default error if you were to run just `npx` in your local terminal.

Comment: @ankidaemon Escaping the double-quotes doesn't work either. I've tried different permutations, it still splits each of those words as a separate argument.

Comment: You did not post the error and what you see when you run docker command, but my assumption `WORKDIR` is not set, or jest is not installed globally, and you docker image have some other entrypoint. you can try `docker run -it -v $PWD/:/app --rm you_image bash -c 'jest -t "it should filter by a search term (link)"'`, I think you do not need npx, just is enough to run your test.

Comment: `node-jest` isn't a standard Docker Hub image, and there are a couple of things at startup time that can cause this.  Can you add your image's `Dockerfile` and any relevant entrypoint script to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention the error, and the quotes seems fine and it should work or run the container with shell, but my assumption is you did not set the `WORKING` directory in your Dockerfile or there is something wrong with Dockerfile

Here is working example taking from [jest docker imag](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/adiii717/jest)e with some [testing code](https://github.com/valentinogagliardi/getting-started-with-jest.git).

```
docker run -ti adiii717/jest sh -c 'npx jest -t "it should filter by a search term (link)"'
```

output:

**Ran all test suites with tests matching "it should filter by a search term (link)".**

```
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File             |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files        |     12.5 |        0 |        0 |    16.67 |                   |
 filterByTerm.js |     12.5 |        0 |        0 |    16.67 |         2,3,4,5,6 |
-----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 skipped, 0 of 1 total
Tests:       3 skipped, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.109s
Ran all test suites with tests matching "it should filter by a search term (link)".
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN npm install jest npx -g
WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone https://github.com/valentinogagliardi/getting-started-with-jest.git /app
RUN npm install
```

Comment: There is no error. In the OP I do say that `jest` works, but only the first word of the quoted match string gets passed to `-t`. I found that `docker run --entrypoint npx -it node-jest jest -t "This string matches exactly one test"` works as desired, but I don't understand why, and would prefer to find a solution without `--entrypoint`. You are right however, it must be something in my Dockerfile, since your example works for me.

Comment: Of all the things it seems to be the `FROM` line in my `Dockerfile`. I'm pulling an internal, corporate node alpine image, and it causes quotes to be treated differently for some reason. As soo as I use `FROM node:alpine` everything works as expected.